# How do you setup an AWS Elastic Beanstalk Docker Platform running Django?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been running a regular Django site using the regular EB Python platform, but for some reasons, I want to migrate to using a Docker image, but still get everything I get from Elastic Beanstalk.
In order to demonstrate the problem, I created a small Django project at https://github.com/dkarchmer/aws-eb-docker-django which works on both Python 2.7 and 3.4, and it is a simplified version of my real site.
Anyway, I will be happy getting this to work with either the Preconfigured Docker Platform, or with a generic Docker platform.
My Google searches have only found the super simple, Flask based example that AWS shows, and a couple of questions on Stackoverflow, but it almost seems like nobody is trying to put a Django project on EB/Docker.
Anyway, lets start with a generic solution, which is my preferred option.
If you download the Github project, you can successfully use docker (or better, docker-sompose) to test that the image works when run locally (I am running on a MacOS). 
It is not clear if I should use a CMD to define specify my "python manage.py runserver" or if I need an ENTRYPOINT, or if I need to use uswgi (as the preconfigured solution does).
I believe I need a CMD, so that is what I am doing:

```
  FROM python:3.4

  RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' myuser

  # Install PostgreSQL dependencies
  # Install Postgres
  RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        postgresql-9.3 \
        libpq-dev \
        libjpeg-dev; \
        apt-get clean

 # Step 1: Install any Python packages
 # ----------------------------------------

 RUN mkdir /var/app
 WORKDIR  /var/app
 COPY requirements.txt /var/app/
 RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

 # Step 2: Copy Django Code
 # ----------------------------------------

 COPY authentication /var/app/authentication
 COPY myproject /var/app/myproject
 COPY settings /var/app/settings
 COPY manage.py /var/app/

 ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings.production

 EXPOSE 8080

 WORKDIR  /var/app
 CMD ["python", "/var/app/manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8080"]
```

You can look (download and try) the code at the Github link above.

When I deploy (see `fab eb_create_custom` in fabfile.py), I get

```
[2015-05-02T15:22:27.245Z] INFO  [1732]  - [CMD-Startup/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/04run.sh] : Activity execution failed, because: 17212f02bce509d43c40eeac9f53a281eecf1502387dac69c096c337c9c7b186
 Docker container quit unexpectedly after launch: Docker container quit unexpectedly on Sat May  2 15:22:27 UTC 2015:
 python3: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory. Check snapshot logs for details. (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError) caused by: 17212f02bce509d43c40eeac9f53a281eecf1502387dac69c096c337c9c7b186
```

I have confirmed the manage.py file is there. I have downloaded the full logs and cannot see much, other than the error above.

Any insides? Anybody knows of an example for running Django on EB Docker?

Thanks

Comment: More inside. If I SSH to the machine and run bash on the docker image, and try to run python manage.py runserver manually, I get `KeyError: 'RDS_DB_NAME'` which tells me that either EB does not set these variables the way it does for a python platform, or it does it on the command-line. But I am going to try hard coding this to see what happens, but if this is it, it will be a pain, as EB is creating the RDS database and I don't know these information in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem.

The problem was that in the Dockerrun.aws.json file, I was mapping (using 'Volumes') a host directory into the `/var/app` container directory, which happens to be where I was `COPY`-ing the project to. This was basically overwriting and replacing all project files. This is why the docker image was working on my local machine (as this file is not needed locally) but failing when releasing to AWS.

Because I don't need to cross map these volumes, I was able to fix the problem by just removing the 'Volumes' entry in the Dockerrun.aws.json.

I have cleaned up and released a working version for others to hopefully find useful:

https://github.com/dkarchmer/aws-eb-docker-django

Answer (score 0):

I still do not have a working custom Docker image, but got the Preconfigured Python Docker version working:

https://github.com/dkarchmer/aws-eb-preconfigured-docker-django